# Object must implement IConvertible in C#

Tags: c#

I get info of coinmarketcap api in C# and store in database but when try get "percent_change_90d" and write in my application get this error:

> Object must implement IConvertible

https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=e0d277bb-ed26-4ed6-b198-dc67cbf48770&start=1&limit=5000

This is my C# code:

```
itm.PercentChnage90D = item["quote"]["USD"]["percent_change_90d"].Value<double?>();

public class CoinData
{
    public string CoinId;
    public string CoinName;
    public string CoinSymbol;
    public double PriceUsd;
    public double PriceBtc;
    public double? PercentChnage1H;
    public double? PercentChnage24H;
    public double? PercentChnage7D;
    public double? PercentChnage30D;
    public double? PercentChnage60D;
    public double? PercentChnage90D;
    public double? Volume24H;
    public double? Circulating_supply;
}
```

How fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: What is `itm.PercentChnage90D`?

Comment: Can"t you do an explicit conversion with `(double) item["quote"]["USD"]["percent_change_90d"]`

Comment: Can the 90 day percent change actually be null, maybe if the coin hasn't been tracked for at least 90 days?  `Nullable` doesn't implement `IConvertible`.

Comment: If you're using `JSON.NET` there is an explicit conversion to `double?` for `JToken` - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_7.htm.  So in that case `(double?)item["quote"]["USD"]["percent_change_90d"]` might work

Comment: issue fixed with: (double?)item["quote"]["USD"]["percent_change_90d"] Thank you  
IllusiveBrian